# Running Tinder on Bluestacks endless "improve location accuracy" popup

Tags: bluestacks

I am trying to run some apps on Bluestacks, eg Tinder, and a popup is always coming up: "this app wants to change your location settings"
No matter whether one pushes yes or no, the popup comes back immediately.
Any tips how to make it go away?

Comment: PS Also had this issue resurface. Reinstalling Bluestacks was the solution as they improved the location feature in the latest version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fix it, you should install Tinder 4.3.5. You can find it on http://tinder.en.uptodown.com/android/old

EDIT: Make sure to uninstall the current one first.

Comment: v4.3.5 still shows the prompt on my S6.

Answer (score 0):

PS the solution was to download Bluestacks 2.x as that works fine with the latest Tinder. Bluestacks 1.x does not auto upgrade to 2.x for some reason. This also allows keeping Tinder updated.